# Microsoft Azure SQL Server with Single Database

Tags: azure, database, sql, microsoft

I have created a Single SQL Database and a SQL Server on Microsoft Azure with a Basic Plant of MAX 2GB. Now I want to create another SQL Database of MAX Size 2GB. Can I create another SQL Database under same SQL Server created earlier? OR I have to create another SQL Server for another SQL Database?

I asked this question because MS Azure Single SQL Database word is making confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can create another Azure SQL DB. When creating DB you can use the existing server or new server